# Given a polygon of n sides and rectangles of sides x and y, find the smallest number of rectangles required to cover the entire area of a polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

I'm trying to write a program on C# on how many tiles are used to cover an area or an irregular shape and if only parts of the tiles are used, then how much area(of the tile is wasted)

Basically, I think it boils down to a single question, that given a polygon of n sides and rectangles of sides x and y, find the smallest number of rectangles required to cover the entire area of a polygon. And furthermore, work out how much area of rectangles is "wasted (if any)"

What I thought about so far is about fixing the longest side of the polygon and keep adding rectangles, but then I think that wouldn't work since the polygon could be concave as well.

Any ideas is appreciated